# How to modify local storage with python requests

Tags: python, local-storage, python-requests

In addition to sending cookies with my python requests request I would also like to send a localstorage key value pair.

I tried looking at the requests docs and it does not look like it is capable in doing this, is it?

Is there a way for me to do this without using a headless browser?

Answer (score 1):

Local storage is not sent with requests. It is accessible via javascript through client-side code. [This website](http://blog.andyhume.net/localstorage-is-not-cookies/) has more information about the differences between local storage and cookies.